Airflow services crashed and perpetually restart
The Airflow service was functioning well. But it crashed after a while and entered a cycle of continuous restarts.
This is an excerpt from the docker-compose log:
repository-redis-1 exited with code 0
repository-redis-1 has been recreated
repository-postgres-1 exited with code 0
repository-postgres-1 has been recreated
repository-postgres-1 exited with code 0
repository-postgres-1 has been recreated
repository-airflow-triggerer-1 exited with code 0
repository-airflow-triggerer-1 has been recreated
repository-airflow-webserver-1 exited with code 0
repository-airflow-webserver-1 has been recreated
repository-airflow-triggerer-1 exited with code 143
repository-airflow-triggerer-1 has been recreated
repository-airflow-webserver-1 exited with code 143
repository-airflow-webserver-1 has been recreated
repository-postgres-1           |
repository-postgres-1           | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
repository-postgres-1           |
repository-postgres-1           | 2024-04-08 12:47:18.867 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.14 (Debian 13.14-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
repository-postgres-1           | 2024-04-08 12:47:18.868 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
repository-postgres-1           | 2024-04-08 12:47:18.868 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
repository-postgres-1           | 2024-04-08 12:47:18.875 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
repository-postgres-1           | 2024-04-08 12:47:18.885 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-04-08 12:47:14 UTC
repository-postgres-1           | 2024-04-08 12:47:18.903 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
repository-airflow-init-1       | The container is run as root user. For security, consider using a regular user account.
repository-airflow-init-1       |
repository-airflow-init-1       | DB: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:***@postgres/airflow
repository-airflow-init-1       | Performing upgrade to the metadata database postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:***@postgres/airflow
repository-airflow-init-1       | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
repository-airflow-init-1       | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
repository-airflow-init-1       | Database migrating done!
repository-airflow-init-1       | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_limiter/extension.py:336 UserWarning: Using the in-memory storage for tracking rate limits as no storage was explicitly specified. This is not recommended for production use. See: https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io#confi
guring-a-storage-backend for documentation about configuring the storage backend.
repository-airflow-init-1       | airflow already exist in the db
repository-airflow-init-1       | 2.7.1
repository-airflow-init-1 exited with code 0
repository-redis-1              | 1:signal-handler (1712580463) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
repository-redis-1              | 1:M 08 Apr 2024 12:47:43.050 * User requested shutdown...
repository-redis-1              | 1:M 08 Apr 2024 12:47:43.050 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
repository-postgres-1           | 2024-04-08 12:47:43.044 UTC [1] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
repository-postgres-1           | 2024-04-08 12:47:43.053 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
repository-postgres-1           | 2024-04-08 12:47:43.056 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 33) exited with exit code 1
repository-postgres-1           | 2024-04-08 12:47:43.059 UTC [28] LOG:  shutting down
repository-redis-1              | 1:M 08 Apr 2024 12:47:43.066 * DB saved on disk
repository-redis-1              | 1:M 08 Apr 2024 12:47:43.066 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
repository-postgres-1           | 2024-04-08 12:47:43.138 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
repository-redis-1 exited with code 0
repository-redis-1 has been recreated
repository-postgres-1 exited with code 0
repository-postgres-1 has been recreated
repository-postgres-1 exited with code 0

I checked and didn't found in the system resources, and rebooting the machine did not resolve the issue.
I think the redis or postgres are the cause of the issue, but don't know why and how to fix it.

Error 143 and some traces say SIGTERM signal was sent to services forcing them to exit. Any idea on which process sent those signals?
